# Do I need to have an ADC plugged into a breadboard?

Tags: gpio, breadboard

I have a MCP3008 - 8-Channel 10-Bit ADC mounted on my breadboard but I am trying to downsize my prototype. Do I need to have the ADC on a breadboard or can I just use female jumpers to attach it to the GPIO pins and just have it hang there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggest will work but is likely to be unreliable.

I may be corrected by the electronics guys but I would suggest the following reliability order.

1. most reliable, ADC soldered into a custom PCB together with the other components and soldered connections between the Pi and PCB.
2. reasonably reliable, ADC inserted into a breadboard with the other components and jumper wire connections between the Pi and PCB.
3. least reliable, ADC and components and Pi connected with jumper wires.

If you go route 3 I would solder all the connections and glue or otherwise mechanically attach the components to a rigid base (to minimise stresses caused by flexing).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any suggestions for downsizing a project?

Comment: I can't help with that.  I'm pretty much a breadboard person.